# Можно ли начинать с изучения java?

Tags: java

Прошу сразу не посылать меня, а дать совет. Перед тем как задавать данный вопрос я залез в гугл, поиск на форуме находил ответы на вопросы. Но все же я хочу уточнить некоторые моменты чтобы не заниматься ерундой. По java интересуют такие области как junior java developer и web developer.

1. В литературе по java пишут, что нужно иметь опыт программирования. Я учусь на втором курсе на программирование, но я пока нахожусь на уровне студента двоечника, поэтому нужно ли мне уметь хорошо программировать на языках программирования таких как С++, pascal и т.д.?
2. Как в одной статье я прочитал, что "Начинать изучение Java желательно c задач, адекватных имеющемуся уровню знания Java.". Где брать такие задания? Сам придумывать пока не в состоянии.
3. Никогда не понимал, как имея определенную задачу, работать с документацией по java?
   Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, что если вы двоечник по C++\pascal, то на Java вы тоже будете двоечником, если срочно что-то не предримите :)

Comment: непродуманно. если человек не понимает преподавателя по программированию, то это еще не означает, что у него нет будушего как у программиста.

Comment: Преподаватель по программированию несущественен (c) borg

Comment: Вы можете выучить совершенно любой язык с нуля. Java имеет достаточно низкий порог вхождения. Даже Haskell можно выучить с нуля (каким бы сложным его не малевали). Но учтите, освоение простейших концепций: (функции, обработка исключений, ООП, стратегии вычисления (Evaluation strategies)) и другие простые вещи будут даваться в вашем первом языке с трудом. Будьте готовы к этому.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Начинать с изучения Java можно.

1. Знание C++ для изучения Java не обязательно, но желательно. Как и при изучении естественных языков, например, знание французского для изучения итальянского полезно, но не необходимо.
2. Надо найти учебники, где эти задания есть. Например, [задачи и упражнения](http://media.samsu.ru/lectures/info/kirillov/lab_work.pdf). Искать по словам: "задачи по Java".
3. Взять качественный учебник с примерами и прочитать его. Затем начать писать простые приложения. Для справки: [начинающим Java программистам](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/43293/).

Comment: Спасибо    .

Answer (score 6):

1. Плохая у вас литература.
2. Поищите сайты фриланса, поищите задания для лаб, курсовых в институте, олимпиад по программированию, офф. сайт java.
3. Непонятно, о какой документации идет речь: RS/UTP или javadoc. RS нужен для того, чтоб описать весь необходимый функционал программы. UTP нужен для того, чтоб сделать тесткейс на каждое требование, описанное в RS. javadoc спасает при поиске средств, - напр., вы давно не работали с БД и забыли, какой метод вам конкретно нужно. Или вы забыли, какой параметр надо передавать, где взять константу, чтоб передать в метод и тд., и тп...

Стать-быть программистом совсем не означает знать какой-то язык. Хотите стать java юниором с уклоном к веб, - не проблема! Вот примерный список того, что можно для этого сделать:

1. хорошо разобраться с ООП, в java эта парадигма - основа языка (класы, интерфейсы, абстрактные класы);
2. изучить базовые классы для того, чтоб при написании программы вы не тратили много времени на поиск (работа с файлами, с сетью, написание ГУИ, сортировки, работа с БД); кроме того, надо не просто сделать простую програмку, надо еще и сделать все, чтобы она стала работать быстрее; (работа в этом направлении даст более глубокие знания средств языка);
3. освоить обработку ошибок и работу с потоками;
4. разобраться с шаблонами проектирования (хотя бы шаблоны создания, прочитав о каком-то шаблоне, попробуйте написать код сами, попробуйте найти его использование в реальном коде, - исходниках java);
5. разберитесь со средствами роботы с Regexp, xml (+ xpath), xsl (это вам пригодится в веб девелопменте);
6. апплеты, сервлеты, jsp страницы (разбираться стоит именно в такой последовательности); напишите клиент, сервер для обмена любыми данными, (напр., сервер погоды, конвертер валют); данные можете брать с какого-то паблик сервера;
7. разберитесь с технологиями ORM, EJB, Spring.

P.S. Научитесь писать хороший код. Если посторонний человек, едва знакомый с программированием (или не знакомый c java), но знающий английский, сможет в нем разобраться, это один из признаков хорошего кода. Хороший код не падает с IllegalArgumentException. Хороший код всегда хорошо отформатирован. Хороший код всегда легко исправить, добавить новый функционал. Хороший код тот, который уже не хочется переписать еще раз (отрефакторить)...

Answer (score 3):

Как работать с документацией поймете, когда придется решить первую задачку. В начале начнете искать куски кода в гугле и его переписывать. Потом прочтете документацию и все станет гораздо яснее. Это неправильный способ, но он часто используется. В любом случаи лучше в начале прочитать книгу и разобраться по ходу пьесы в коде. Лучше даже переписывать куски кода прямо из книги, без кнтрл ц кнтрл в, задавая себе вопросы "что значит эта строчка". Вы научитесь читать документацию тогда, когда начнете ее писать - javsdocs для этого отличный пример.
Про книги. Брюс Эккель дает хорошее внутренние понимание почему так, но нету задачек. Не плохо описано у Шилдта, есть упражнения к каждой главе, но книга давно не переиздавалась. Если она будет по java 1.5, а лучше 1.6, тогда читайте смело. И есть Хорстман. Упражнений тоже нету. Язык сложный, но описано просто все.
Еще лучше читайте на английском. На удивление, многая переводная литература на русский язык читается хуже, чем на оригинале. Среднего знания англ вполне хватит.

Важнее скорее всего не знание другого языка, а мышление. Мне было тяжело учить яву после паскаля, т.к. нужно было перестроиться на ООП. Алгоритмеческое же мышление должно быть всегда.

Теперь про работу. Java - это только первый шаг) Чаще всего сейчас разрабатывают под веб, а это знание Java ЕЕ. Где знание EE, там и базы данных(SQL). Нет баз данных - значит XML. Всего, понятное дело, сразу не выучить. Поэтому начните с джавы, потом возьмите ЕЕ, а SQL вас должны научить в университете.

Answer (score 3):

Яву начал изучать, уже имея некоторый опыт в изучении С++. Как выше сказали умные люди - не надо задаваться вопросом, что НУЖНО знать, для того, чтобы изучать Яву. Это уже автономный, ни от чего не зависящий язык. Нужно просто захотеть разобраться, четко определить цель изучения и проявить упорство. Так что угодно можно изучить. Только не падайте духом, если встретите сложные задания, с которыми будет трудно разобраться. Упорство и труд - все перетрут) Удачи в изучении!

Answer (score 3):

Например в Мюнхенском техническом университете программирование изучают с 1 курса и именно на  Java Core!!!

Comment: Не холивара ради. Вот что думает Джоэл Спольски об обучении на Java.
http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java

Comment: @mvcdev, спасибо, интересная статья. Прочел с удовольствием.

Comment: Больше восклицательных знаков!!!!!!

Comment: и не забудь ровно столько же =========

Answer (score 3):

Да можно, я так и начал, но не с книг, а с ресурса, в котором теория дается понемногу, но сопровождается большим количеством задач с автоматической проверкой.

Если начнешь со сложных тем - есть большой шанс, что неудачи и непонимание тебя оттолкнут, поэтому перед Java не стоит учить другие языки. Java намного проще чем C++ и позволяет довольно быстро почувствовать магию программирования. При это не смотря на простоту, Java очень мощный язык. Так что однозначно ДА - стоит начинать именно с Java.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, совершенно не важно с чего начинать. Начинать надо с того, что интересно. Потому что вас либо затянет и вы станите хорошим программистом, либо поймете, что это не ваше. А выучить второй-третий язык программирования это не проблема. Конечно если это вам по душе.

Я вообще с Flash + Action Script начинал, потому что это весело (мультики, игрушки там всякие).

Answer (score 1):

С++ знать не обязательно. Но насколько я понимаю чистая JAVA скорее идет для программирования серверов и различных устройств. Если для WEB то вам понадобится JavaScript. И вообще можно все это узнать в Википедии.

Comment: Java можно использовать как для разработки standalone приложений, так и для web (JSP).
JavaScript - это не JAVA.

Comment: Для веб я что то чистой явы не встречал.

Comment: Я в скобках выделил - JSP - JavaServer Pages.

Comment: servlets, jsp, jsf, adf-jsf, beans, pojo, jdbc, applets(ха-ха:).
На java написаны spring, hibernate, tomcat. Вот вам и чистая java для веб.